# For part (ii), how can I prove that using Fermat's Theorem?

Tags: number-theory

[image]

In this question, I think I know how to do part (i), $p^q+p^q-p-q=p(p^{q-1}-1)+q(q^{p-1}-1) $and then using Fermat's Theorem. In part (ii), I try to do $p^{q^3+q}= p^{q(q^2+1)}$, but I do not know what to do next. Can anybody help? Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. One form of Fermat's Theorem is $p^q\equiv p\pmod{q}$.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not actually know how to do the p^((q^2)+1) part

Comment: $p^{q^2}=(p^q)^q\equiv p^q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
p^{q^3 + q} \equiv p^{q(q^2 + 1)} \equiv (p^q)^{q^2 + 1} \equiv p^{q^2 + 1} \equiv p^{q + 1} \equiv p^{1 + 1} \equiv p^2 \pmod q
$$

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Work backwards:

If this follows from Fermat Little Theorem, then $q^3+q-2$ must by divisible by $q-1$. And yes it is:

$$q^3+q-2=(q-1)(q^2+q+2)$$

Therefore 
$$q^3+q=(q-1)(q^2+q+2) +2$$

**added** P.S. If $P(x)$ is any polynomial with integer coefficients and $a$ is not divisible by $q$ to calculate 
$$a^{P(q)} \pmod{q}$$
you simply need to divide $P(q)$ to $q-1$. This can be easily obtained by dividing $P(X)$ at $X-1$, long division tells us that
$$P(X)=(X-1)Q(X) + P(1)$$
Now plugging in $x=q$ and using FLT you get
$$a^{P(q)} \equiv a^{P(1)} \pmod{q}$$

In the above computation $P(1)=2$.